# windows installer custom action install & uninstall both called when upgrade 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, custom-action

Excel AddIn, VS2010, C#, Windows Installer

VS2010, Setup project, RemovePreviousVersion: True, DetectNewerInstalledVersion: True, InstallAllUsers:True

I have some install, uninstall codes in Custom Action

When I do a upgrade install, I notice, install is called first, which installs newer version, and then uninstall is called, which uninstalls the newer version. The end result is not-working AddIn left.

If I do a new install (i.e. no earlier version of AddIn), then only install is called and addin installs successfully

Installer used to work fine when I built it in VS2008, and I just converted projects to VS2010 and then the issue comes up.

Anyone know why ? thanks

Comment: Solved. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854311/web-setup-project-removes-files-after-upgrade-from-vs2008-to-vs2010 

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered in comment under my question. Now answer it explicitly for convenience in search.

I edited my MSI-file in Orca resequenced RemoveExistingProducts right after InstallInitialize (sequence number 1501). This was found in the InstallExecuteSequence table. This was originally sequence number 6550.

Pls refer [Web setup project removes files after upgrade from VS2008 to VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854311/web-setup-project-removes-files-after-upgrade-from-vs2008-to-vs2010)

Answer (score 2):

You likely have `RemoveExistingProducts` scheduled incorrectly - I don't know if this can be changed in VS Setup Packages, but that will be the action that is causing all your pain.

Comment: thank you, Sir. This is not exposed in VS setup. How to check/correct it ? I only know about orca. thanks

Comment: I use ora to take a look at RemoveExistingProducts, in InstallExecuteSequence, it is between InstallExecute and InstallFinalize. I did a compare of msi generated from VS2008 and that from VS2010, and can't tell difference as far as RemoveExistingProducts and InstallExecuteSequence. Still can;t figure out why they behave different. thanks

Comment: I check table RemoveFile is empty but still a lots of files are removed in Action RemoveFiles

Comment: what is this in CustomAction table, one row having Action:_D5BA2A17_DAA5_49D8_B762_FE982EFC7566.uninstall, Type: 3073, Source: InstallUtil, Target: ManagedInstall. What is _D5BA2A17_DAA5_49D8_B762_FE982EFC7566?

Comment: @toosensitive - sorry, I'm not familiar enough with VS setup packages :(